# Non-decreasing expectated value of non-decreasing function with family of probability density satisfying monotone likelihood ratio property.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value, estimation

I am trying to prove the Lemma(3.4.2)(1) of book "Testing statistical hypotheses" by Lehmann and Romano, its statement is " If $\{p_{\theta}(x)\}$ be a family of densities on the real line with monotone likelihood ratio in $x$ and if $\phi(x)$ is a non-decreasing function of $x$, then $E_{\theta}(\phi(X))$ is a non-decreasing function of $\theta$."

In the proof, let $\theta^{'}>\theta$ and define $A$ and $B$ are the set of $x$ such that $p_{\theta^{'}}(x)<p_{\theta}(x)$ and $p_{\theta^{'}}(x)>p_{\theta}(x)$ respectively. Let $a=sup_{A}\phi(x)$ and $b=sup_{B}\phi(x)$ then it is clear that $b\ge a$.

Now consider that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  \int \phi(x)(p_{\theta^{'}}(x)-p_{\theta}(x))dx&=\int_{A}\phi(x)(p_{\theta^{'}}(x)-p_{\theta }(x))dx+\int_{B}\phi(x)(p_{\theta^{'}}(x)-p_{\theta}(x))dx \\
&\ge a\int_{A}(p_{\theta^{'}}(x)-p_{\theta }(x))dx+b\int_{B}(p_{\theta^{'}}(x)-p_{\theta}(x))dx \\
&= (b-a)\int_{B}(p_{\theta^{'}}(x)-p_{\theta }(x))dx \\
&\ge 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
My doubt is that it is nowhere mentioned in the statement of lemma that $\phi(x)$ is non-negative than how is he writing
\begin{equation}
\int_{A}\phi(x)(p_{\theta^{'}}(x)-p_{\theta }(x))dx\ge a\int_{A}(p_{\theta^{'}}(x)-p_{\theta }(x))dx.
\end{equation}
Am i trying it wrongly?, Is there any other way through which without taking $\phi(x)$ non-negative it can be proved.

Thank you for any hint/explanation.

Answer (score 2):

On $A$ we have $\phi (x) \le a$ and $p_{\theta'}<p_{\theta}$. So, $p_{\theta'}-p_{\theta}<0$.

$c\le d$ and $t<0$ implies $ct \ge dt$ right?

Comment: Thank for the help